# PHP Laravel Framework Database Connection Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I created a database called learning-laravel and I created a table which is users I want to get data from that table I wrote this code block:

```
Route::get('/',function()
{   
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    return $users;
});
```

but I'm getting this type of error:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (2)



  */
    public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
    {
        $username = array_get($config, 'username');

        $password = array_get($config, 'password');

        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

Comment: is this the correct host? `localhost:8889`

Comment: yeah mysql settings is keeping in localhost:8889

Comment: can you show the code where you specify the host and port number?

Comment: my database.php file 'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost:3306',
   'database'  => 'database',
   'username'  => 'root',
   'password'  => 'root',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  ),

Comment: I checked my MAMP server APACHE post:8888 MySQL post:3306 I think there should be no error

Comment: Your database.php file port and your error port don't match...

Also, why are you using non standard ports for HTTP? Is that a laravel thing (Haven't used that framework yet)

Comment: according to your comment, your port number is 3306

Comment: what's the standart port for HTTP?

Comment: yeah 3306 i changed my all setting everything should be match but error still here :(

Comment: That port would be 80. You know what ports are used for, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of including the port in the host, add a "port" key and the port in a seperate key.

```
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => '8889'
```

Looks like it may be trying to use that entire string as the host name.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment above, you have your MAMP settings pointing MySQL requests to port 3306. Here is the correct setting in that case:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '3306'
```

Also, the "is it plugged in" suggestion would be to make sure your DB is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
'host'      => 'localhost:3306',
```